# Bash: extract columns with cut and filter one column further

Tags: bash, awk, grep, cut

I have a tab-separated file and want to extract a few columns with `cut`.

Two example line

```
(...)
0    0    1    0    AB=1,2,3;CD=4,5,6;EF=7,8,9    0    0
1    1    0    0    AB=2,1,3;CD=1,1,2;EF=5,3,4    0    1
(...)
```

What I want to achieve is to select columns 2,3,5 and 7, however from column 5 only `CD=4,5,6`.

So my expected result is

```
0    1    CD=4,5,6;    0
1    0    CD=1,1,2;    1
```

How can I use cut for this problem and run `grep` on one of the extracted columns? Any other one-liner is of course also fine.

Comment: Does it have to be done with `cut`? `awk` would be much better for this, since you can use the `split()` function on that column to extract a part of it.

Comment: He said any other one-liner is also fine so you can probably go ahead and give him your `awk` answer

Comment: `awk` is also perfectly fine, I just thought of cut as first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is another `awk`

```
$ awk -F'\t|;' -v OFS='\t' '{print $2,$3,$6,$NF}' file

0       1       CD=4,5,6        0
1       0       CD=1,1,2        1
```

or with cut/paste

```
$ paste <(cut -f2,3 file) <(cut -d';' -f2 file) <(cut -f7 file)

0       1       CD=4,5,6        0
1       0       CD=1,1,2        1
```

Comment: My favorite solution is with `cut` and `paste`.

Answer (score 3):

Easier done with `awk`. Split the 5th field using `;` as the separator, and then print the second subfield.

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS="\t"; OFS="\t"} 
     {split($5, a, ";"); print $2, $3, a[2]";", $7 }' inputfile > outputfile
```

If you want to print whichever subfield begins with `CD=`, use a loop:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS="\t"; OFS="\t"} 
     {n = split($5, a, ";");
      for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        if (a[i] ~ /^CD=/) subfield = a[i];
      }
      print $2, $3, subfield";", $7}' < inputfile > outputfile
```

Comment: What would I change if the amount of entries in the 5th field is not always the same (and not always contains `CD=...`)?

Comment: So you want to print whichever entry in the 5th field begins with `CD=`, not always the 2nd entry? That wasn't obvious from the question, since the result is the same either way with your example input file.

Comment: That's true, thank you for pointing that out, that was not clear to me in the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

I think `awk` is the best tool for this kind of task and the other two answers give you good short solutions.

I want to point out that you can use `awk's` built-in splitting facility to gain more flexibility when parsing input. Here is an example script that uses implicit splitting:

*parse.awk*

```awk
# Remember second, third and seventh columns
{
  a = $2
  b = $3
  d = $7
}

# Split the fifth column on ";". After this the positional variables
# (e.g. $1, # $2, ..., $NF) contain the fields from the previous
# fifth column
{
  oldFS = FS
  FS    = ";"
  $0    = $5
}

# For example to test if the second elemnt starts with "CD", do 
# something like this
$2 ~ /^CD/ {
  c = $2
}

# Print the selected elements
{
  print a, b, c, d
}

# Restore FS
{
  FS = oldFS
}
```

Run it like this:

```
awk -f parse.awk FS='\t' OFS='\t' infile
```

Output:

```
0   1   CD=4,5,6    0
1   0   CD=1,1,2    1
```